# Efficiently extract multiple columns into variables

Tags: shell, awk

This seems like it should be simple, but has been driving me nuts trying to find a way to phrase a search to answer it.

Quite simply I have a file structured as three columns consisting of a name, a path, and a pattern. While looping through the lines I would like to extract each of these into its own variable for use.

The solution I have currently is (forgive typos):

```
while read line
do
    name=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    path=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    pattern=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}')
done < "myFile.txt"
```

However this seems a really inefficient way to do it as it means invoking `awk` once for each variable. So, is there a better way to do this? The delimiter is just a tab at the moment, but I can change it to anything that's easier to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while read name path pattern
do
    # Do something
done < myFile.txt
```

And if you want to change your delimiter to something else, like a `,`:

```
while IFS=, read name path pattern
do
    # Do something
done < myFile.txt
```

Comment: You can simply prefix the `read` command with the correct delimiter, rather than changing it globally: `while IFS=, read name path pattern; do`.

Comment: **slaps forehead** Staring me right in the face all along! Thanks for the quick response, hopefully my question comes up for anyone else searching for something they should already know =)

Comment: An additional query, but if I don't know how many columns I have, is it possible fetch an arbitrary number of remaining columns? For example, if my the first column of each line was a command, and the rest were arguments. Is it possible to do `while read cmd the_rest`?

Comment: Yes.  If there are more fields to read than you have specified names for, the remaining fields are assigned to the last name.  You can easily test this.